# Is there a way to get Android Studio to generate <p> elements instead of <p/> when formatting JavaDoc?

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8, javadoc

Android Studio has a setting: `'Generate "<p/>" on empty lines'` under `File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > JavaDoc`. When reformatting a Java file, Android Studio will place a `<p/>` element in wherever there is an empty line in the javadoc description.

Generating javadoc (can use `Tools > Generate JavaDoc`) will result in this error:

```
error: self-closing element not allowed
* <p/>
```

Is there a way to keep this behavior, but use `<p>` instead of `<p/>`?

---

**Configuration**

- Studio Build: Android Studio 1.4
- Build #AI-141.2288178, built on September 28, 2015
- Version of Gradle Plugin: 1.3.0
- Version of Gradle: 2.4
- Version of Java: 1.8.0_60-b27 amd64
- OS: Ubuntu 14.10 (64-bit)

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: My question is whether there is some incorrect configuration I am using, or if this is really a bug. When searching for similar issues, I couldn't find anyone discussing this (one mention in someone's build script on github). I would think this issue would be problematic for many people. Should I remove this post and instead wait for a response on AOSP Issue Tracker?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio seems to do this automatically now. I'm on version 1.5.1

it will even replace existing `<p/>` tags with `<p>`.